# Qt cannot open input file 'qtmain.lib'

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

I've tried to compile Qt on my system. After almost 17 hours of waiting for nmake to complete, I finally got it all working except for one thing.

Initially VS was complaining about not being able to open QtCore.lib. I actually only had QtCore4 so i deleted the lib directory on the additional includes in the linker and added the QtCore4 and QtGui4 individually.

Now I'm getting a complaint about qtmain.lib. I've also added that in the linker however for some reason it's not picking it up - even though its there. I do NOT want to do nmake and waste another 17 hours waiting for it to complete. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

Comment: Need much more details. Which Qt version? What error message exactly? What exactly did you "add individually", where did you get them? Overall, randomly deleting something and adding back doesn't sound like a way to get anything working, unless you really know what you are doing and why. Lastly, SO might not be the best place to get answers for a question like this. Qt irc channels, mailing list or forums might work better. And while you're wondering, perhaps start a new compilation following the instructions extra carefully, in case you don't find solution in 17 hours...

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/visual-control/wiki/Compiling

Comment: Thats where i've got the code and i'm trying to get everything working. If you've got Qt and OpenCV then you could try it out because i'm having no luck whatsoever trying to get it working. Perhaps my linker are all messed up.... :(

Comment: You could try with precompiled Qt 4.8.5 for MSVS2010, I think Qt download page has them.

Comment: Anyway, I meant, add details of what you did to the question by editing it. Most important is the compile/link command that fails and the exact error message.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out. But I downloaded a fresh batch of everything and have a new problem. Some classes are divided by filters and for some reason they are unable to see.  Each other. Not sure why....

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "divided by filters", and "unable to see each other" is also pretty vague. But in the context, as a wild guess you are perhaps not adding all the libraries (and/or their include files) correctly to the project. But if you have a new question, please post a now SO question for it.